# Showing up JUnit test results from Ant script in Eclipse -- is it possible, at all?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit

In my attempt to implement a JUnit test suit through Ant, I stumbled across the question of whether it'd be possible to make the suite results show up in the typical Eclipse JUnit window, when run from Eclipse.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use Right-Click -> Open With -> JUnit View on the XML result file to achieve this.